# How to load web font in my email layout for gmail

Tags: html-email, woff

I'm trying to add font to my email template. I'm hosting that font because I'm using it on my website. I insert that font like below:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: homsa;
    src: url('www.mysite.net/fonts/IRANSansWeb(FaNum).woff')  format('woff');
}
```

but the font in my email won't change. I test it with gmail and putsmail.com for sending email to my gmail

Answer (score 2):

Gmail along with Outlook 2007-2019 has no support webfonts.

My suggestion is to find a similar font supported by Gmail to use as a fallback.

```
font-family: homsa, sans-serif;
```

- https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts

Good luck.